# Dropbox Captures the Internet

Tags: dropbox

I recently installed Dropbox on my computer.The problem is that when Dropbox is syncing i.e. uploading or downloading no I cannot use internet on my other programs like firefox. On the other hand this does not happen in Linux Mint(Cinnamon) 15 or Windows 8 which is installed on the same computer. Not only this any other computer connected to the same Wifi router, their internet is diabled too. The current system on my computer Kubuntu 13.10 32bit version, I recently upgraded from version 13.04. I asked the support team of Dropbox and this was their reply.

> "Hi Mazhar, Thanks for contacting Dropbox. Unfortunately Dropbox can only upload and download as fast as your internet service provider
> (ISP) allows. Consumer ISP's normally provide 1/10th the upload speed
> compared to download speed. Normally Dropbox doesn't use all of your
> bandwidth, just to be polite.  However, you can change that by
> manually setting the upload/download speed:
>
> 1. Right click the Dropbox
>    icon in the system tray at the bottom right of your screen, by the
>    clock on Windows or menu bar at the top of your screen on Linux.
> 2. Click on the gear icon in the Notifications panel and select "Preferences" from the menu
> 3. Click the "Network" tab
> 4. Click Change Settings next to Bandwidth:
> 5. Set the Upload and Download to a specific kB/s limit if you know your connection speed or simply Don't Limit to allow Dropbox to use as much bandwidth as possible.
>
> NOTE:
> Setting your Upload to Don't Limit or a higher number than your
> connection is capable of will likely cause all other internet activity
> on your network to slow significantly.

Unfortunately this did not not help.Please solve this problem.

Comment: How could it "capture" the traffic? You can't browse at all, or it is just slow? If your router allows you, setup a QoS (see manual!).

Comment: I second B.Roland, what sort of error are you getting in your web browser while it is syncing?

Comment: There is no error message, the Internet just stops working on other applications.My wife who uses Windows 8 on a different Notebook but connected to same router, her Internet stops working. If I pause or quit Dropbox then everything is fine again.

Comment: I think I might have solved this problem. I uninstalled and then reinstalled Dropbox through Muon Package Manager. After that in preference menu of Dropbox I set upload bandwidth limit to 10 kibs, earliar the option was set to limit upload bandwidth automatically, and it was uploading at around 24 kibs anyway. After setting the limit to 10 kibs the Internet is working fine so far.
Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question earlier

Comment: BTH the message on Firefox is " Server Not Found " I have a screen Shot too but don't know how to attach here.

Answer (score 0):

You'll probably find that the other installations of dropbox (if they're installed) on your  linux mint and windows 8 installs are already sync'd with dropbox.  Either that or they have few differences to sync.

If you've just installed dropbox on this o/s and dropbox is set to use a different storage location from the other installs, then the first time you sync dropbox, all the files will be synced.  If you have lots of data, then it'll take lots of time.

The chances are it's the download that's consuming the bandwidth if indeed this is a new install.

My suggestion, set it going overnight and let it catch up.

Comment: I think I might have solved this problem. I uninstalled and then reinstalled Dropbox through Muon Package Manager. After that in preference menu of Dropbox I set upload bandwidth limit to 10 kibs, earliar the option was set to limit upload bandwidth automatically, and it was uploading at around 24 kibs anyway. After setting the limit to 10 kibs the Internet is working fine so far.
Thanks for taking the time to reply to my question earlier